# How do I insert one Node-chain into another node-chain

Tags: java, nodes

Good evening, I have a question. I have a Node class that I created:

```
public class Node {
private int value;
private Node next;
private Node prev;

Node(int value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
}

Node(int value, Node next) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = next;
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public Node getNext() {
    return next;
}

public void setNext(Node next) {
    this.next = next;
}

public void printXXX() {
    System.out.println("Node : " + this.value);
}




public boolean hasNext() {
    if(this.next != null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And I have a task to print a new Node chain where I need to insert one Node-chain into another Node-chain somewhere in the middle using a function. For example `Node1[25,28,32,39,60,70]` `Node2[43,49,52,58]` and I want a function to return `Node[25,28,32,39,43,49,52,58,60,70]`

I have a code shown here:

```
public class Main {

public static void createANewChain(Node node1, Node node2) {
    boolean flag = false;
    while(node1.getNext() != null) {
        if(node1.getNext().getValue()>node2.getValue()) {
            node1.setNext(node2);
            flag = true;

            while (node2.getNext() != null) {
                node2 = node2.getNext();
            }

            //node2.setNext(node1.getNext()); //error
        }
            else
         {
             node1 = node1.getNext();
        }


    }

    if(flag == false) {
        while(node1.getNext() != null) {
            node1 = node1.getNext();
        }
        node1.setNext(node2);
    }


}

public static void printANewChain(Node node1) {
    while(node1.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(node1.getValue());
        node1 = node1.getNext();
    }
    System.out.println(node1.getValue());
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Node n6 = new Node(70);
    Node n5 = new Node(60,n6);
    Node n4 = new Node(39,n5);
    Node n3 = new Node(32,n4);
    Node n2 = new Node(28,n3);
    Node n1 = new Node(25,n2);


    Node g4 = new Node(58);
    Node g3 = new Node(52,g4);
    Node g2 = new Node(49,g3);
    Node g1 = new Node(45,g2);





    createANewChain(n1,g1);
    printANewChain(n1);

}


}
```

In the end, I get an infinite loop. So, the problem is that after linking the first Node to the second I lose all those parts of a chain that were supposed to go after linking `Node2`

`Node1[25,28,32,39]` ...  `[60,70]` - I lose them

In the task, all numbers from `Node2` should be in the gasp between two specific numbers in `Node1`

Please, help me to find a solution on how to link two of these Nodes. I hope I explained the task clearly.
Have a nice day and thanks for your solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It is simpler than this. But first, your function definition isn't right. You need to specify which node to append to, and which to insert, like

```
public static void createANewChain(Node nodeToAppendTo, Node nodeToInsert) {
```

Then, what you need to do is

set the node following nodeToAppendTo previous value (nodeToAppend.next.prev) to nodeToInsert's last element, and vice versa (nodeToInsert last element . next = node following nodeToAppendTo, and set nodeToAppendTo's last element likewise)

Then set nodeToAppendTo.next to nodeToInsert, and nodeToInsert.previous to nodeToAppendTo

This is how you insert one linked list into another.

Because I think this is a homework problem, I have left it for you to code up what I have pseudo-coded

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, I solved this problem by myself Idk whether it's a bad or good algorithm.

```
public static void createANewChain(Node node1, Node node2) {
        boolean flag = false;
        while(node1.getNext() != null) {
            if(node1.getNext().getValue()>node2.getValue()) {


                Node copy = node2;
                while (copy.getNext() != null) {
                    copy = copy.getNext();
                }

                copy.setNext(node1.getNext());

                node1.setNext(node2);

                flag = true;

                while (node2.getNext() != null) {
                    node2 = node2.getNext();
                }

            }
                else
             {
                 node1 = node1.getNext();
            }


        }

        if(flag == false) {
            while(node1.getNext() != null) {
                node1 = node1.getNext();
            }
            node1.setNext(node2);
        }


    }
```